# Rails command Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was working on a project earlier today when suddenly my rails commands stopped working. I know that I must have introduced something that created an error but for the life of me I don't know what. The error that I get whenever I type any rails commands (for example, rails c, rails s, rails -v etc) is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
1: from /Users/mccoleman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
/Users/mccoleman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/mccoleman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/exe/rails (LoadError)
```

The following is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2', '>= 5.2.2.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'rspec'

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
# gem 'rack-cors'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'rb-readline'
end


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I've tried searching for similar errors but haven't been able to find anything that looks similar. Any ideas why rails suddenly isn't working?

Comment: does your `bundle` run without any issues ?

Comment: Have you added any gem? Try bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at RVM's [gemset](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics). Set a gemset for your project, use it, install and run bundle.

```sh
$ cd myproject
$ rvm create gemset mygemset
$ cat 'mygemset' > .ruby-gemset
$ cat 'ruby-2.5.1' > .ruby-version
$ cd .
$ gem install bundle
$ bundle
```

`.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` allow RVM to set your Ruby version and gemset automatically when you `cd` to you project.

Comment: Thanks CAmador I came across that somewhere else and tried it without success.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm still not 100% sure what caused the error to occur, I was able to rectify it by uninstalling and then reinstalling rails.